# How to display for my code?

Tags: java

My question is how do I display the 2D array which I stored.

1. Specifically, my program needs to display the elements (in somewhat a table) which I stored in them for each month.
2. Next, it should sum up all the values stored(do I use another array for that?), and display them in a line, e.g. (`System.out.println("Total amount spent for the month of January is....."`)

All help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class test {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");
    static DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    static String months[] = { null, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }; // to store month data
    static String monthItems[][] = new String[13][13];
    static double amount[][] = new double[13][13];
    static int m = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter month <1 for Jan - 12 for Dec>:  ");
            m = input.nextInt();
            if (m == 0) {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Invalid month!");
                System.out.println();
                return;
            } else {
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(months[m] + " Expenditure <max 10 items>");
            // to store data if January is selected
            MonthData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // error message to inform user of wrong input
            System.out.println("Invalid month!");
        }

        try {
            System.out.print("Enter month <1 for Jan - 12 for Dec> :  ");
            m = input.nextInt();
            EntryMonth();
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Expenditure for " + months[m] + ":");
            // to display monthly data
            DisplayMonthData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // when user enter's wrong input
            System.out.println("Invalid month!");
        }
    }

    static void EntryMonth()// to allow user to enter month data
    {
        try {
            if (m < 1 || m > 12) {
                return;
            } else {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static void MonthData() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter item " + (i + 1)
                        + " <Press ENTER to exit> : ");
                monthItems[m][i] = input.next();
                if (monthItems[m][i].length() == 0) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Enter amount : $");
                    amount[m][i] = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    static void DisplayMonthData() {
        for (int row = 0; row < amount.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < amount[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.println(monthItems[row][column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a JTable for display.  If you can come up with a more specific question, ask it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson                                                                                                                                                                                                        Let say the month chosen is January.The user types in a value for the item field and the amount field.Next the user must be able to display that item alongside its value for that month.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways, but here's something which should already help you.

```
  static void DisplayMonthData()
  {
    for(int row=0;row<amount.length;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<amount[row].length;column++){
            String monthItem = monthItems[row][column];
            if (monthItem==null)
                System.out.print("\t")
            else
                System.out.print(monthItems[row][column]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
```

If you want the totals next to each line, refactor out the part that prints one line, and make it sum the values in that line.  Then add the end, add a `print(total)`.

Edited to skip null values.

Comment: Tried that but all it displays is null values and $0.00.Any more advice you can share?

Comment: @PuppetMinds: that's trivial.  See the edit.  For the 0.00 at the end, you're probably not adding them up right.  Why do you have both MonthItems and amount?  I'm thinking you should probably display the amount, not the monthitems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment Joeri Hendrickx' answer, but he is correct. I just tried your code, entered `10 (enter) foo (enter) 5 (enter) bar (enter) 7 (enter) (enter) 10 (enter)` and it displayed everything just fine. Of course all but two items are null and all but two amounts are 0.0, but that is just as expected.

Comment: So how do I NOT display those null values?